# Html code used along with Matlab

Tags: html, matlab, latex, html-helper, matlab-uitable

I have recently found that Matlab can use LaTeX character sequences. However, they only can be used by the functions text, title, xlabel, ylabel and zlabel. I have designed a GUI which has an uitable. Its header is a string that uses HTML code and looks like this:

```
headers = {'<html><center>Component X<br />(km/s^2)</center></html>', ...
           '<html><center>Component Y<br />(km/s^2)</center></html>', ...
           '<html><center>Component Z<br />(km/s^2)</center></html>'};
```

My intention is replacing s^2 with s squared. Because of I can not use LaTeX characters inside the string "header" (at least I have tried it and it has not worked), I would like to know how I could do it if I use HTML code which I do not know.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you for your comment. If you write it as an answer, I would be pleased to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For writing superscripts in HTML, use the `<sup>...</sup>` pair:

```
headers = {'<html><center>Component X<br />(km/s<sup>2</sup>)</center></html>', ...
           '<html><center>Component Y<br />(km/s<sup>2</sup>)</center></html>', ...
           '<html><center>Component Z<br />(km/s<sup>2</sup>)</center></html>'};
```

Answer (score 2):

For the superscripts appearing in units in diagram titles and labels I always use the designated Unicode characters like `km/s²` or `kg/m³`. 
These numbers are available: `ⁿⁱ⁰²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹`
This works even in software that does not allow LaTeX charactrer sequences (if the selected font has the corresponding characters and if the software is Unicode capable). The same numbers are available as subscript also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has allowed me to learn new knowledges (I love it).